# What POM dependency would allow Maven to find this JAR?

Tags: java, maven, mockito

I'm trying to import Mockito into a Maven Java project. In order to build, I need to use artifacts in my companies Maven repository.

Fortunately, I do find a Mockito artifact in the repository:

```
[my-company]/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.8.0/mockito-all-1.8.0-jvm15.jar.
```

If I add the following dependency to my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.0-jvm15</version>
</dependency>
```

then maven tries to find the jar in a non-existent directory:

```
[my-company]/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.8.0-jvm15/mockito-all-1.8.0-jvm15.jar
```

If I remove the `-jvm15`, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then (naturally) maven tries to find the a nonexistent jar in the right directory:

```
[my-company]/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.8.0/mockito-all-1.8.0.jar
```

Is there a way to specify the path that works around the seemingly non-standard naming in my companies repository? I need the artifact in our internal repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part after the version is called the classifier. Try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <classifier>jvm15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a classifier tag -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.0</version>
     <classifier>jvm15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Exactly correct. I often upvote more than one answer, but 5 minutes late is too much to get credit for the exact same answer.